# Ktor request url adding ://localhost:80

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I'm working with Ktor Client on Android and facing an issue. The issue is the Request URl which I am supplying to client gets changed automatically
My actual request Url is

```
https://app.getbonzo.com/oauth/token
```

When I make a call the url automatically becomes

```
https://app.getbonzo.com/oauth/token://localhost:80
```

It is adding **://localhost:80** at the end of each url I pass to my client
I cannot find what's the issue here.

Here is what I am currently doing

Here is how I am setting up my client

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies{
 //Ktor dependencies
    def ktor_version = '2.2.4'
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
    // Client Engine
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
    //Android Client
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")
    // HTTP engine: The HTTP client used to perform network requests.
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version")
// The serialization engine used to convert objects to and from JSON.
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
// Logging
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"
    // content Negotiation
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
    // Json
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")
    //XML
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-xml:$ktor_version")


    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.1"
}
```

**HttpClient**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class ApiModule{
    @Provides
    fun getKtorHttpClient()  = HttpClient(Android) {
        expectSuccess = true
        engine {
            connectTimeout = 15000
            socketTimeout = 15000
            proxy = null
        }
        // Logging
        install(Logging) {
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
        // JSON
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                useAlternativeNames = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                encodeDefaults = false
            })

        }
        // Response Validator
        HttpResponseValidator {
            validateResponse { response ->
                val error: KtorErrorModel = response.body()
                if (error.code != 0) {
                    throw CustomResponseException(response, "Code: ${error.code}, message: ${error.message}")
                }
            }

            handleResponseExceptionWithRequest { exception, request ->
                val clientException = exception as? ClientRequestException ?: return@handleResponseExceptionWithRequest
                val exceptionResponse = clientException.response
                if (exceptionResponse.status == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
                    val exceptionResponseText = exceptionResponse.bodyAsText()
                    throw MissingPageException(exceptionResponse, exceptionResponseText)
                }
            }
        }

        // Timeout
        install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = 15000L
            connectTimeoutMillis = 15000L
            socketTimeoutMillis = 15000L
        }
        // Response observer
        install(ResponseObserver) {
            onResponse { response ->
                Log.d("HTTP status:", "${response.status.value}")
            }
        }
        // Apply to all requests
        defaultRequest {
            KtorNetworkApi.headerMap.apply {
                if (!isNullOrEmpty()){
                    forEach{
                        header(it.key,it.value)
                    }
                }
            }
            // Content Type
            accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }
    }
}
```

**Making Post request**

```
suspend fun login(
        email:String?,
        password:String?,
        
    ){

        val model = LoginRequestModel(
            BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID,
            BuildConfig.CLIENT_SECRET,
            BuildConfig.GRANT_TYPE,
            BuildConfig.SCOPE,
            email,
            password
        )

        runCatching {
            ktorClient.post {
                url("https://app.getbonzo.com/oauth/token"){

                }
                setBody(model)
            }
        }.onSuccess {
            if (it.status == HttpStatusCode.OK)

            else{

            }
        }.onFailure {
            Log.d("error_API","${it}")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `url("https://app.getbonzo.com/oauth/token") {}` call assigns the `https://app.getbonzo.com/oauth/token` string to the scheme of an URL. To solve your problem, remove the second parameter (`{}`) of the `url` method call:

```
ktorClient.post {
   url("https://app.getbonzo.com/oauth/token")
   setBody(model)
}
```